# XlsxWriter writing date as number

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, date, xlsxwriter

I am writing date to a file and i am using:

```
date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

and i am writing date object to excel file:

```
worksheet.write(row_count, column_count, r, formatter)
```

where `formatter` is aligning it in the middle and `r` is the object in the current loop.

It shows like `10/28/2016` but i want it to be saved as a number value (like `42871` for example). Is there any way this to happen within code and not manually in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the XlsxWriter documentation on [Working with Dates and Times](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html#working-with-dates-and-time) a date in Excel is just a number with a format. If you omit the format you get the number:

```
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('datetimes.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column so that the dates are visible.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Create a datetime object.
date_time = datetime.strptime('2017-05-16', '%Y-%m-%d')

# Create a format for the date or time.
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd mmmm yyyy'})

worksheet.write('A1', date_time, date_format)
worksheet.write('A2', date_time             )

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This solution worked. Problem is i formatted the date before i write it and when i write it automatically writes as `%m/%d/%Y`

Answer (score 2):

The number value in Excel is what I'm assuming as the days since epoch, which in this case is January 1st, 1900. Refer to [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252). However, in practice you would want to use Dec 30, 1899 to account for leap years. All you have to do is run a diff check and then get the days from the epoch.

Assuming your date is 10/28/2016:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> new_value = (date(2016,10,28) - date(1899,12,30)).days
42671
```

Therefore, before you write your rows, just do some upfront calculation:

```
new_value = (your_date_in_the_row - date(1899,12,30)).days
```